# How to open multiple browsers and do web automation parallelly using cefsharp

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I want to use cefsharp and my current project requirement is to open multiple web browsers with multiple websites and do web automation in parallel. I know a term IPC (inter process communication), but never used it.

Can someone provide some sample code to achieve the said requirement using cefsharp or any other alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `IPS`? You'd typically automate using `ChromeDriver`, which should basically be the same for all `CEF` derived frameworks like `CefSharp`. See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md

Comment: @amaitland, thanks for your comment.. By IPS i meant inter process communication. Can you direct me to some example of using chrome driver for cefsharp? I need to open many webpages and dosome automation on those pages in parallel. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not aware of any `CefSharp` specific examples. Most users seem to be able to get it working without issue. Probably best to update your two questions to include `IPC` instead of `IPS`.

Comment: @amaitland, any example in cefsharm or any other library to do parallel processing of more than 2 pages would be sufficient me to understand the process!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I'm not aware of any. So you'll have to do your own research. Anything `ChromeDriver` related should be relevant.

Comment: @amaitland, I understand. But I want to tell you that I am able to run cefsharp samples but these sample are just opening webpages in tabs or saving screenshots one after another means synchronously.

I am rephrasing my question again; I want to run multiple cefsharp browser and each browser is opening a URL and then application is doing some automation on that URL and reporting the progress to the main form. AND all browsers running and doing automation in PARALLEL.

Comment: It may or may not be possible, you'll have to experiment/piece things together yourself. You maybe better of looking at something like https://multibrowser.com/